# How to display and control full-screen video in an XBOX game

Tags: xna, xbox360

I would like to create a game for XBox360 which is mostly full-screen HD videos. The player will be given choices during the game to determine which video is to be played.

I need very fine-grained control over the video such as controlling playback speed, seeking to video frames and possibly applying simple effects to the videos.

I also want to be able to use augmented reality to add elements to the videos so I need to be able to render 3d objects over the video.

It would be great if this could be done in XNA however there is only basic video playback functionality there. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

Your options for decoding videos are limited. The `VideoPlayer` class provides functionality for playing videos from the start, pausing and resuming them, looping them, and setting their audio volume.

As far as displaying videos goes - you have a huge degree of freedom. You basically get each frame of the video as a texture that you can draw as a sprite, or apply to any 3D object. This includes using it as an input to a pixel shader, allowing you to apply all kinds of effects to the video.

The only alternative to the built-in player is to create your own. If you want to target the Xbox 360 this will limit you to managed code only. I am not aware of any suitable video decoder libraries.

For Windows, a little Googling revealed [this library](http://xnadsplayer.codeplex.com/), which may be a good starting point.